# How to insert 'n' number of rows based on 'n' being a number in a cell

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a list of companies in column a. In column b, I have a number. I need to create a list where the company appears as many times in the list as the value of the number:

```
Company A    4
Company B    2
Company C    3
```

I want:

```
Company A
Company A
Company A
Company A
Company B
Company B
Company C
Company C
Company C
```

So, it's sort of a 'Create (n) Duplicates' function.

Comment: Do you need these to be in a column? If you just want them to be in a cell, a quick solution is (say in Column C) to use `=Rept(A1&" ",B1)`.  That will repeat what's in cell A1 (followed by a space) a certain number of times, determined by B1.

Comment: I need them in a column. I can see how your solution works, (upvote for that) but it doesn't give me a single column, it gives me several rows.

Comment: how many rows is your original list?

Comment: 30 rows, with some needing duplication up to 9 times

Comment: see my answer below. I gave you VBA, because the amount of manual work to do it with Excel functions is way to much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KopyKat()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
   Dim v As String, kk As Long, m As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   K = 1

   For i = 1 To N
      kk = Cells(i, "B").Value
      v = Cells(i, "A").Value
      For m = 1 To kk
         Cells(K, "C") = v
         K = K + 1
      Next m
   Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Is that some sort of script / code? Where do I put that?

Comment: @Bevan  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this really all that easy / feasible to do just formulas or manual Excel functions, based on your list, so here is VBA procedure to do the job.

To use this click `Alt + F11` inside of Excel. Go to Insert > Module. Then paste it in the module and run it (after adjusting for data ranges and sheet names.

```
Sub MakeList()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet name

With ws

   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In .Range("A1:A3") ' assumes list in cells A1-B3
        .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(c.Offset(, 1)).Value = c.Value 'builds list in column C
   Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: :( i cannot mark this as an alternative answer. It works, as does @Gary's Student answer. Thankyou both.

Comment: Clever use of using `Offset()` to adjust the range. I would have thought to use the number as a variable and just paste X times.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the similar problem, but could not use VBA (using Teams/Excel Online). This relies on REPT, FILTERXML function and helper columns.

**Helper columns D,E,F (one for each company, can be further streamlined)**

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&LEFT(REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1),LEN(REPT(a1&"</s><s>",B1))-7)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

**Parsing:**

REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1) - creates a string of A1 repeated B1 times, separated by "</s><s>"

LEFT(REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1),LEN(REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1))-7) - remove trailing "</s><s>" (which is 7 characters long) from the string above

Prepend/append (&) "<t><s>" and "</s></t>" to the string above
"<t><s>"&LEFT(REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1),LEN(REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1))-7)&"</s></t>"

FILTERXML = parse the final XML string

**Display all in one column**

```
=SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,D:F)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

**TEXTJOIN** creates an XML string from non-empty (TRUE) cells

**FILTERXML** creates an array

**SORT** array to display in alphabetical order

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but the answer of selytch doesnot work on Mac because FILTERXML is not available. I found a solution but an intermediate column is necessary. I give anyway my solution, it can help someone :

Formula in column C is :

```
=REPT(A1&"@",B1)
```

and formula in D1 is :

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C1:C6),"@"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vvHo.png)