# Insert Rows Based On Cell Content and expand

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I've done next to no vba coding for excel but I am familiar with vba coding for access. Any and all help is very much appreciated!

The example used in this question is just a snipped of the amount of data is actually present, so please keep in mind the code will need to accommodate for up to 100+ rows.

I need to expand and fill the following table, `tbl1`:

[image: tbl1]

with data from the following table, `tbl2`:

[image: tbl2]

I would like the output to look like this, `tbl3`:

[image: tbl3]

I have attempted to break this into parts, first I had used **countif** to determine now many times the `suburb` appears in `tbl2` and then insert rows of that amount under the respective row, however I found that it doesn't actually insert the rows but more so appends data to existing rows. I wanted to insert rows in the hopes that column `team` can remain merged for that particular `district`. I cant seem to 'insert' rows, like you would when you right click, insert row.

Another problem im having is getting the additional data in `tbl2` into the output `tbl3`. I know I cant use **vlookup** because there are multiple matches for each value, i'm not sure how to proceed.

**EDIT**
tbl2 in reality will contain much more data than tbl1 requires, each row will have different combinations of values for example: `Cat, Red, South` but we are only interesting in the values that are in tbl1 to expand and fill tbl1.

Comment: This isn't a "real" table right? Fairly sure you can't merge rows in a table. So inserting shouldn't do the whole row, since excel doesn't expect that. Have you tried `EntireRow.Insert`? Or `EntireRow.Resize(x).Insert` where `x`is your amount of rows to insert.

Comment: Do you have merged rows? My recommendation is to get rid of those first.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly then you do not need VBA for this. Use `vlookup` in 4th column of `tbl2` and pull data from `tbl1` that will get your `district`. In 5th column of `tbl2` again pull data from `tbl1` using `vlookup` to get your `team`. Use `Location` i.e the 3rd column as lookup text for `vlookup`.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber sorry I was unclear, I do not mean that this table is 'formatted as table' ("real") table. Its just in a sheet in excel. I have not tried that, will give it a go thanks!

Comment: This is also an easy task for PowerQuery 
`= Table.NestedJoin(tblAnimals, {"Location"}, tblSuburbs, {"Suburb"}, "tblSuburbs", JoinKind.LeftOuter),` But you need to remove the merged cells.

Comment: I just tested it with vlookup and it works exactly as shown in tbl3 (Minus the merged part)

Comment: @Storax I have merged rows, I need these rows merged for the final product (tbl3).

Comment: In my expericece merged cells only causes headaches but, of course, that is up to you.

Comment: Not sure why you are ignoring my comments... but still i have posted an answer to support my above comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: If you mean me sorry, but I do not see any comment of you related to one of my comments.

Comment: no @Storax :) The comment is intended at OP

Comment: Ok thanks, just wanted to make sure

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry I am not ignoring you, just slow at typing haha.My understanding is that Vlookup will give me the value located in the first row what the vlookup detects a match. So if I need to find 'animal' and use vlookup suburb of west, it will only return dog (not cat). I just saw you post an answer though so ill investigate and get back to you :) thanks!

Comment: `Vlookup will give me the value located in the first row what the vlookup detects a match` Oh yes. I am counting on that to get my `Team` data as there are merged cells ;) check the answer that I posdted

Comment: @SiddharthRout I pressed enter prematurely, ive edited my comment above

Comment: Yes I was reading that but the idea (for ease) is not to populate `tbl1` or `tbl2` but create a new table `tbl3` and then replace `tbl1` with `tbl3`.

Comment: @Storax yeah the merged cells are probs not the best to have in the meantime, easier to add at the end. thanks will try!

Comment: @SiddharthRout and storax upvotes for your solutions! Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the Powerquery solution. I started with two tables (listobjects resp. intelligent tables in Excel) which I called tblAnimals and tblSuburbs.
[image]

I imported these tables into Power Query (Goto Data and From Table/Range) and saved them in PowerQuery as connection only. Then I joined these two queries (Data, combine queries) with Suburb as the column for the join.

[image]

The result is

[image]

And this is the M-Code to do it

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(tblAnimals, {"Suburb"}, tblSuburbs, {"Suburb"}, "tblSuburbs", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    combineSuburbs = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "tblSuburbs", {"District", "Team"}, {"District", "Team"}),
    reorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(combineSuburbs,{"Suburb", "Animal", "Colour", "District", "Team"})
in
    reorderColumns
```

Comment: very elegant thank you. Just confirming this would still work and yield the same result if tblAnimals had other records that did not fit the criteria to be joined with tblAnimals?

Comment: Yes, you can change the kind of join depending on your needs https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/join-types-in-power-query-see-how-it-works/ or filter data which have no match.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly then you do not need VBA for this.

**Logic**

1. Use `VLOOKUP` in 4th column of `tbl2` and pull data from `tbl1`. That will give you the **District**. Use **Location** i.e the 3rd column as lookup text for `VLOOKUP`.
2. In 5th column of `tbl2` again pull data from `tbl1` using `VLOOKUP` to get your **Team**.  Use **District** i.e the 4th column as lookup text for `VLOOKUP`.

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

Now copy `tbl2` and paste it as shown below and add 2 columns **District** and **Team**

[image]

In cell `D19` put the formula `=VLOOKUP(C19,$C$1:$E$7,2,0)`

[image]

And in `E19` put the formula `=VLOOKUP(D19,$D$1:$E$7,2,0)`

[image]

Simply drag the formula and we are done.

[image]

Comment: How do you get the merged cells without doing anything manuallly at the end?

Comment: If merged cells are really necessary, then for that one can write a very basic macro which will reverse loop and merge same value cells

Comment: Hi @siddard, thanks for your answer. Just a reminder this is just an example and the real data set contains 150+ records. My first comment is the that tbl2 is a table with 1400 records that I would like to pull data FROM that is, not every record in tbl2 will be pulled. The data that will be pulled are the ones that are present in tbl1 hence why I specify that tbl1 needs to be expanded and filled. Reverse engineering this problem would not be feasible for this particular dataset. I really appreciate your input and I apologise if I was not clear enough in asking my question.

Comment: `The data that will be pulled are the ones that are present in tbl1` I am slightly confused @pewpew But there is no data in `tbl` except the last 3 columns. Are you not trying to put tbl2 data in tbl1? Your tbl3 looks like you are taking all animals into account?

Comment: @SiddharthRout another comment as the box would fit my whole comment before: Clarifying my comment 

"The data that will be pulled are the ones that are present in tbl1" 

tbl2 has 1400 rows, tbl1 has 150 rows. only 150 rows of data will be pulled from tbl2 to fill tbl1. My apologies again for my crappy explanations. If I find a solution I'll be sure to let you guys know! Thanks for all your input :)

Comment: `tbl1 has 150 rows. only 150 rows of data will be pulled from tbl2 to fill tbl1.` @pewpew What is the criteria to fill tbl1? It cannot be suburb, district, team

Comment: @SiddharthRout if youre interested in full problem I can email you the full datasets and provide a complete understanding. In short tbl1 contains records from a the full tbl2 that the client has sent to us and said 'we need to find other one similar to this that have the following values in fields x, y ,z' So to answer your question, criteria to EXPAND THEN FILL tbl1 (in other words replace tbl1 with tbl3) comes from tbl2, suburb, district team. I have found a solution, but had to do additional steps to the data - not the only solution im sure. I will share it with you all in one moment.

Comment: @pewpew I would recommend editing your question with all details so that others can also pitch in :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a **partial** solution to the above.

This is a solution to expand tbl1 to include the data from tbl2.

For this to work, I needed to count how many times a suburb in tbl1 appeared in tbl2, i did this using `=countif()` then appended each count next to the column like below:

[image: newtbl]

Then I used code found in this post [Insert 'n' number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288517/how-to-insert-n-number-of-rows-based-on-n-being-a-number-in-a-cell) to get the following table:

[image: newtbls]

I then used the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim FindEnd As Range
 
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim text5 As String
 
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Text As String
Dim Text4 As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text3 As String
Dim l As Integer
    
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim address1 As String
Dim address2 As String
 
i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
 
text2 = "start"
text3 = "start2"

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("e1:e332")
 
For Each rng2 In rng
    text2 = rng2
    
    If text2 = text3 Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        i = 1
    End If
    
    Set rng3 = Sheets("test").Range("E:E")
    Set FindEnd = rng3.Find(What:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    address1 = FindEnd.address
    text5 = "E" + CStr(rng2.Row)
    l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E1:" + text5), rng2)
    
    Do While j < l
        Set FindEnd = rng3.Find(What:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=FindEnd)
        j = j + 1
    Loop
     
    j = 1
    LastRow = FindEnd.Row
    Text = "G" + CStr(LastRow)
    Text4 = "G" + CStr(rng2.Row)
            
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Text4).Value = Sheets("test").Range(Text).Value
    k = k + 1
    
    If k = 500 Then
        Exit For
    End If
    
    text3 = rng2

Next rng2
End Sub
```

To get a table like this:

[image: newtbl22]

This will need to be repeated/aletered slightly to get the 'Animal' column.

Now as advised by @storax in the comments above, the merged columns are probably going to be a big problem. So I unmerged them all and then used @siddharth solution to fill the district and team columns.

[image: final]

From here I will need to write some code to merge duplicates in column. Using @siddharth full solution will work for the purpose of this example, however as stated, the full dataset is far bigger and hence this was a more viable solution for that. Thank you to everyone for all your help. If there is still interest Ill post the solution for the merging too but I think there will be an answer for that somewhere on stackoverflow.

Thanks agains and much appreciated for all your input.

Comment: If you unmerge the cells anyway then Powerquery should help you and at the end you can merge the cells again.