# How to insert and copy 'n' number of rows based on 'n' being a number in a cell

Tags: excel, duplicates

I'm looking to use the [https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student%27s) answer to this question [How to insert 'n' number of rows based on 'n' being a number in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288517/how-to-insert-n-number-of-rows-based-on-n-being-a-number-in-a-cell?newreg=50825edc715c4c8086f393e9578181ff).  I have a similar scenario, a list of items with various quantities of each item which I need to set out in a new sheet with one row per item iteration.

[Original List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpls3.png)       [Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMsn1.png)

I am not quite sure how to modify the VBA to read columns in one sheet and set up the new list in another sheet.

[vba code and simple result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YJ3g.png)

Are "A", "B", and "C" defined ranges?  And will this work if the source list is filtered?

Comment: "Cells" is usually used with row and column Number, for instance C5 is Cells(5,3), But, less usually you can also used the row Letter in a cell reference. So, in this case, A, B and C are references to the A, B and C column. So, `Cells(i,"B").Value` gets the value of the i'th cell in column B.         The code in your link is simple and only uses one sheet, creating column C from the info in Cols A and B. Instead, you will need to switch to another sheet at "For m" and switch back after "Next m". Google Worksheet.Activate.

Comment: Thanks for that @Stax. I hacked together a workaround using a working column in my target worksheet which duplicates the source list. The simple code runs on that working column. Not elegant but it seems to work.  I'll give your suggestion a go to clean it up a bit.